# Get View of RecyclerView by AdapterPosition

Tags: java, android, view, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a RecyclerView with video previews in it. 
When the user is scrolling, the videos should automatically be played on the recyclerView-items which are visible to the user (when scroll-state is IDLE).

So I've written a custom onScrollListener which passes the positions which are visible to the user as an array to the method `startVideosOn(int[] positions)`.

But the problem is when I want to get the View by the position (the position equals the adapter position). When I try `linearLayoutManager.getChildAt(index)` I get `null` when the 3rd item is displayed, because the RecyclerView has only 2 childs, which will be recycled.

So how do I manage to get the `View` of the RecyclerView by adapter position?

Edit, this is the OnScrollListener:

```
public abstract class AutoPlayRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    public AutoPlayRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.linearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

            if (firstVisibleItemPosition != -1 && lastVisibleItemPosition != -1) {
                playOn(firstVisibleItemPosition, lastVisibleItemPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    private void playOn(int lower, int upper) {
        int[] completelyVisibleItems = new int[upper - lower + 1];

        for (int i = lower, j = 0; i <= upper; i++, j++) {
            completelyVisibleItems[j] = i;
        }

        playOn(completelyVisibleItems);
    }

    public abstract void playOn(int[] items);
}
```

Comment: post you scroll listener code

Comment: tried `RecyclerView#findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int position)` or `RecyclerView#findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(int position)` ?

Comment: @pskink Can you post this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: you can find the solution here . [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52557308/5872337)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you need to get any `View` for a visible "position" either use:

```
RecyclerView#findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int position)
```

or

```
RecyclerView#findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(int position)
```

the returned `ViewHolder` will hold the `View` you want

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't find this.

Comment: Probably because it is in `RecyclerView` class and not in `RecyclerView#Adapter` wich is the one we mostly work with…