# RecyclerView get View by position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` and each `CardView` contains a `TextView` and an `ImageView`. Whenever I click an item, I want to set the image visibility to VISIBLE and to set the previous clicked item image's visibility to INVISIBLE.

This is my Adapter class :

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private Context context;
private List<Category> lista;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private IncomeCategoryActivity activity;

private static final int CATEGORY_REQUEST=6;
private static final int ITEM_EDIT=1;
private static final int ITEM_DELETE=2;
private static final int EDIT_REQUEST=7;

private int current_pos=-1;


public CategoryAdapter(List<Category> lista, Context context, IncomeCategoryActivity activity) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
    this.activity=activity;
    layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view, activity);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.imageView.setImageURI(lista.get(position).getUri());
    holder.textView.setText(lista.get(position).getCategory());
    holder.position = position;
    holder.category=lista.get(position);

    if(holder.category.isChecked()==true){
        holder.imageViewCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        current_pos=position;
    } else {
        holder.imageViewCheck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener{
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView imageViewCheck;
    public int position;
    public Category category;
    public IncomeCategoryActivity activity;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, IncomeCategoryActivity activity) {
        super(itemView);
        this.activity=activity;

        imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.customCategoryImageView);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.customCategoryTextView);
        imageViewCheck=itemView.findViewById(R.id.customCheckImageView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String aux=textView.getText().toString();
        if(aux=="CATEGORIE NOUĂ"){
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, CustomIncomeActivity.class);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CATEGORY_REQUEST);
        }
        else{
            imageViewCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int pozitie_check=getLayoutPosition();
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, AddIncomeActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("categorie_venit", aux);
            intent.putExtra("position_check", pozitie_check);
            activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            activity.finish();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Selectează acțiunea");
        MenuItem edit=menu.add(0, ITEM_EDIT, 0, "Modifică");
        MenuItem delete=menu.add(0, ITEM_DELETE, 0, "Șterge");

        edit.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        int position=getLayoutPosition();
        if (item.getGroupId() == 0) {
            if(item.getItemId()==ITEM_EDIT){
                Category category=lista.get(position);
                Intent intent=new Intent(activity, CustomIncomeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("edit_icon", category.getUri());
                intent.putExtra("edit_category", category.getCategory());
                intent.putExtra("list_position", position);
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_REQUEST);
            }
            else if(item.getItemId()==ITEM_DELETE){
                lista.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
    return true;

}
```

At this moment, whenever I click an item, there are two images VISIBLE on the `RecyclerView`: the clicked item's image and the previous clicked item's image. I think I need to get the previous View by its position and to manually set the visibility to INVISIBLE.

Comment: what about first time you click on item ??? no previous clicked item ???

Comment: First time I enter the Activity all images are invisible. When I first click an item, the image becomes visible.

Comment: you want all image is invisible. Only that image visible which is clicked???

Comment: Exactly, there is only one image visible at a moment

Comment: have look on my answer and let me know ??

Answer (score 11):

`recycleView.getChildCount()` and `recycleView_parent.getChildAt()` only gives the **Adapter items** which is shows only screen .
that means if your list has 200 items and the only 5 items shows on screen so we can find only 5 item with the help of **recycleView**

i am using one simple **trick** to solve the issue.

1. You can define Hashmap which hold your **holder objects**

   ```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<Model> dataList;
        Context context;
        HashMap<Integer,ViewHolder> holderlist;


    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Model> dataList, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
        holderlist = new HashMap<>();
    }
   ```
2. And after that to save the holder in Hashmap

   ```
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if(!holderlist.containsKey(position)){
            holderlist.put(position,holder);
        }
   ```
3. Create a method in Adapter.

   ```
   public MyListAdapter.ViewHolder getViewByPosition(int position) {
            return holderlist.get(position);
        }
   ```
4. Call this method from your **Activity** or whenever you want.

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < datalList.size(); i++) {
                MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder = ((MyAdapter)recycleView.getAdapter()).getViewByPosition(i);
                View view = holder.itemView;
                TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.tv);

    }
   ```

Comment: This is the best solution, as this will never return null on recycled, all other methods will return null whenever user scroll the recycler.Best approach <3 save my day.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: I tried with your solution. But I got only screen visible data after that non visible bottom itemview is null. So can you suggest me the solution for this.

Comment: Hi @khushbuvadi,
i think you try to get item without scroll end of the buttom.

public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     if(!holderlist.containsKey(position)){
         holderlist.put(position,holder);
     }
this method only store all viewholder object once you visit at least single time

Answer (score 1):

I have created the demo you can refer it and implement for single selection

```
 recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerView.Adapter() {
        int selected_position = -1;

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.row_color_list,parent,false)) {
                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return super.toString();
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ImageView imageView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

            if(selected_position == position){
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(selected_position != holder.getAdapterPosition()){
                        selected_position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 20;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This should be written in my Adapter class?

Comment: in this code i have to show you the way you show hide the image so just refer the code . In this code you have to refer how i used  the int variable selected_position 
to show hide the item just check and implement at your own in the adapter and if you still don't  understand feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following:

1) Declare a global variable:

```
private int selectedPos = -100;  // Put any irrelevant number you want
```

2) Set selected position `onClick()` :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    selectedPos = getAdapterPosition();
}
```

3) Check selected postion and assign visibility inside `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(position == selectedPos){
        holder.imageViewCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.imageViewCheck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }     
}
```

Comment: It's working, but when I start again the Activity, I want the last clicked item's image to be visible.

Comment: Then you have to store the `selectedPos` in `SharedPreference` and get the value in adapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
add this code into adapter class for handling click event..

```
 OnItemClick onItemClick;

public void setOnItemClick(OnItemClick onItemClick) {
    this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
}

public interface OnItemClick {
    void getPosition(String data); //pass any data to shared it.
}
```

after bind method..

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    final String str=mStringList.get(position); //  here your boject
    if(holder.category.isChecked()==true){
        holder.imageViewCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        current_pos=position;
    } else {
        holder.imageViewCheck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick.getPosition(str); // pass your data.
        }
    });
}
```

after bind adapter into recycler view it means adapter not null then called below code..

```
        adpater.setOnItemClick(new RecyclerViewAdpater.OnItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void getPosition(String data) {
            // hear update your value for check into if condition.
            data="sdfsdf";

            adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

and also read comments and also try to make custon class and access that object value and update after click it..
this code only how to handle click event into recycler view.

Comment: The thing is when I start again the Activity, I want the last clicked item's image to be visible

Comment: that time you stored value into shared preference and when bind adapter data that time pass shared preference value into update class object.